Dropdown Menu ONLY Appearing When Logged In - Not even a button
I'm having a problem where the hamburger drop-down menu only appears when I'm logged in, I tried on multiple devices and I tried clearing the cache and removing all plugins.
https://localbridalexpos.com/
